# Do good tests enable sloppy coding?

Tags: testing, code-reuse

Let's say you're coding, and you come across an opportunity for simple code resuse (e.g. pulling a common piece of code out to an accessible place like a Utility class or base class).   You might find yourself thinking, "I know it's good to do this, but I have to get this done now, and if I need to make a change to **this** code, and forget to change it in the other place, my testing framework will let me know."

In other words, you let the awesome tests you (or another developer) has written to remind you to change the code in the other places too.

Is this a legitimate problem that we might find in ourselves or other developers?

Comment: I can't say I understand what you think the problem is.  It sounds like what you described is pluses all around.  You feel empowered to change your crappy code, and the tests remind you if you screw it up too badly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking whether unit tests encourage you to rely on them as a method of TODO list? Yes, but I don't think that's sloppy coding. You are, afterall, to start with unit tests failing and code to the test; if you refactor some code and then once again code to the test, that isn't sloppy coding -- it's doing what you're supposed to.

I think the problem with unit tests is simply that you can't cover every corner case in a unit test, and sometimes people assume that a working test means a working app, which isn't true.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you provide, good tests are in fact enabling you to implement sloppy design, however in my experience, bad tests wouldn't have discouraged you from doing the same.

The fallacy in your argument centers around the premise that "getting this done now" means you will save time by implementing sloppy design. The truth of the matter is that you are incurring technical debt whether your tests are good or not. Making a change to that code is now a much more complex task, whether you have a good testing framework to remind you of that or not.

> Although immature code may work fine
>   and be completely acceptable to the
>   customer, excess quantities will make
>   a program unmasterable, leading to
>   extreme specialization of programmers
>   and finally an inflexible product.
>   - [Ward Cunningham](http://c2.com/doc/oopsla92.html)

The strength of good testing practices may be in allowing you to incur that debt with some level of safety. As long as you continue to be aware that this area of the code is now weak, as a result of your choices, then it may be worth the tradeoff -- you ship your product sooner, at the cost of higher debt, with a lower risk of incurring bugs in the short run as a result.

Answer (score 1):

If the tests are good and the code (sloppy or otherwise) pass them, all is good. It would be nice to have good code but sloppy working code is better than good broken code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use tests as my first option to finding the code that needs changes. I'll use my IDE's search (or refactoring) functionality and look for all the places that call the method in question.

The tests are just a nice addition in case I was accidentally sloppy or accidentally introduced a bug. Test don't make me sloppy from the start, they just reassure me once I think I'm done.

Comment: Well, there are some weird cases when enough meta-programming makes your IDE search function less useful. Although you could then argue that perhaps your software is relying too heavily on meta-programming.

Comment: I you write a macro maze then your IDE might not find all the callers of a method. But a plain old Find All on: "methodName" should still find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that good tests enable you to fix sloppy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly write incredibly sloppy code with or without tests.  Unit testing makes it slightly easier to get away with it, but only in the short run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of logic copied in two places in your code (IMO the worst thing a developer can do), then you probably have inconsistent tests as well.

The most important job any programmer can do is ruthlessly refactor the code, removing ALL duplication.  This almost always shows benefits on even a single iteration.

Why would you think if you had an error in copied code in 2 places that your tests would be any better?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more to me like sloppy developers and sloppy coding practices are what are leading to sloppy code in your example. The tests you described would *prevent* the sloppy code from ever getting to far.